# How do I specify a span tag as the 'Name' of the link, in the link_to helper in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So my link_to looks like:

```
<%= link_to compare_stage_path(stage, :access_key => client.authentication_token) %>
```

But I would like to make the following span the link that links to the above path:

```
<span class='edit-icon'> </span>
```

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want that span tag as the content of the anchor element for the link, right?  In that case...

```
<%= link_to "<span class='edit-icon'> </span>".html_safe,
            compare_stage_path(stage, :access_key => client.authentication_token) %>
```

Comment: Perfect, how do I get it to launch the link in a new window ? I tried adding `:target => '_blank'` but all that happened was that it added the attribute `target=_blank` to the URL, such that it turned into `stages/7/compare?access_key={token}&target=_blank` which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Nevermind, I did it wrong. I had put `:target => '_blank'` inside the `compare_stage_path()`, when I should have added a comma and put it outside of it. Once I did that, it worked. Thanks.